React- vite deploying to netlify
I just purchased and made some examples for myself. I want to deploy it to Netlify. I have created an account, installed netlify-cli, ran npm run build, and deployed. However, nothing shows up on the screen. I can see everything when I run npm run preview. What should I do? Thanks.
https://deppokeremm.netlify.app/
The error on site
index-b5f4faea.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
